# Split a matrix column wise using mat2cell function [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab

If I have a `matrix A` of size `(500,30)` and want to split it into several submatrices of sizes `(500,3)`,that is, 10 submatrices in this case.

How can we do that using the inbuilt `mat2cell` function?

The idea is to keep the same number of rows of the submatrices as the original matrix `A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mat2cell](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) can split a matrix into a cell array.

```
A = rand(500, 30);
C = mat2cell(A, 500, [3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]);
```

As we can see [mat2cell](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) takes 3 arguments. The first is the matrix to split up, the second the size of the rows which must sum to the number of rows in said matrix, the third the size of the columns which must sum to the number of columns in said matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much